# What is the difference between YUVFormat.YUV_420 and ColorSpace.YUV420?

Tags: java, jmf, color-space, fmj, jcodec

I have searched through and have read a ton of sources, but I cannot seem to find an answer. I thought these "types" were equal, but when I decode h264 into bytes using jcodec I assumed the data output was YUV 4:2:O Planar (YUV420P); this is the expected input type for my VPX encoder. The VPX encoded image looks like this:
[image]

So I have to assume that while YUVFormat.YUV_420 is most likely YUV420P, the ColorSpace.YUV420 is some other variant of YUV420. Does anyone know which variant it is so that I can find a conversion routine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One format interlaces the u and v data for a full scan line. the other writes the entire U and then the entire v data. These are after the entire Y image. yuv420 and yuv420p specifies which layout. yuv420 writes all the u then all the v data, yv420p interlaces the u and v data scan line by scan line. This image can be a little misleading because the data size is small enough to not show large blocks of u and v pixels.

[image: yuv420 non P]

I believe yuv420p would interlace the U1U2U3 V1V2V3 U4U5U6 V4V5V6

Comment: I tried swapping the u and v and it didn't change the picture too much, theres still lots of pink

Comment: @Andy-S: I believe the above image _**is**_ YUV420P, where you first have the block with Y-values, then the block with U-values and finally the block with V-values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting yuv420sp instead of yuv420p.  This would explain the horizontal bars in the image.  Semi Planar formats interleave the U and V planes.

```
// 420p to 420sp
int frameSize = width * height;
int qFrameSize = frameSize / 4;
for (int i = 0; i < (qFrameSize); i++) {  
    input[frameSize + i*2] = (input[frameSize + qFrameSize + i]);  
    input[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = (input[frameSize + i]);   
}
```