# Copying frames from camera (/dev/video0) to framebuffer (/dev/fb0) gives unexpected result

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, camera, framebuffer, v4l2

I have been trying to show frame from raspberry camera to screen with near best performance, and after research I found that the best way could be to use V4L2 library to directly communicate to drivers.

In the next section I present my code. It could characterize to be longer for *Stack overflow*, but I commented every block of code, so It can be more understandable.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define CAM_WIDTH 1280
#define CAM_HEIGHT 720
#define CAM_FORMAT (v4l2_fourcc('B','G','R','A'))

#define CAM_BUFFERS 1

int main(void)
{
    int cam_fd; 
    int fb_fd;

    struct v4l2_capability cap;
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers reqbuf;
    struct v4l2_format fmt;
    struct v4l2_buffer buffinfo;
    enum v4l2_buf_type bufftype;

    char *cam_buffers[6];
    int cam_buffer_size;
    int cam_buffer_index = -1;

    char *fb_p;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;

    /* Setting framebuffer */   
    fb_fd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if(!fb_fd)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to open framebuffer\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                return -1;
        }
    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo);
    if(ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to get framebuffer info\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Framebuffer: resolution %dx%d with %dbpp\n\r", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, vinfo.bits_per_pixel);

    fb_p = (char*)mmap(0, vinfo.xres*vinfo.yres*4, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, 0);

    memset(fb_p, 0, vinfo.xres*vinfo.yres*4);

    /* Setting camera */
    cam_fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if(!cam_fd){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Couldn't open device\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Couldn't retreive device capabilities\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    if(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Device is not a capture device\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    if(cap.capabilities & V4L2_CAP_STREAMING == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Device is not available for streaming", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Set image format */
    memset(&fmt, 0, sizeof(fmt));
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    fmt.fmt.pix.width = CAM_WIDTH;
    fmt.fmt.pix.height = CAM_HEIGHT;
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = CAM_FORMAT;
    fmt.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;
    if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to set image format\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    cam_buffer_size = fmt.fmt.pix.sizeimage;

    /* Request buffers */
    memset(&reqbuf, 0, sizeof(reqbuf));
    reqbuf.count = CAM_BUFFERS;
    reqbuf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    reqbuf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &reqbuf) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Mmap streaming not supported\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    if(reqbuf.count != CAM_BUFFERS)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%S:%i: Not all requared buffers are allocated\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Query and Mmap buffers */
    for (int i=0; i < CAM_BUFFERS; i++)
    {
        memset(&buffinfo, 0, sizeof(buffinfo));
        buffinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buffinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        buffinfo.index = i;
        
        if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buffinfo) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to query buffers\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return -1;
        }
        
        cam_buffers[i] = mmap(NULL, buffinfo.length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, cam_fd, buffinfo.m.offset);
    
        if(cam_buffers[i] == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to enqueue buffers\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return -1;
        }
    }   
    
    /* Enqueue buffers */
        for (int i=0; i < CAM_BUFFERS; i++)
        {
                memset(&buffinfo, 0, sizeof(buffinfo));
                buffinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buffinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buffinfo.index = i;

                if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buffinfo) == -1)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to enqueue buffers\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                        return -1;
                }
        }    

    /* Start Streaming */
    bufftype = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &bufftype) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to start streaming\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        fd_set fds;
        struct timeval tv;
        int r;

        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(cam_fd, &fds);
        tv.tv_sec = 2;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        
        r = select(cam_fd+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        if (r == -1) {
            if (errno = EINTR)
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Call to select() failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return -1;
        }
        if (r == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Call to select() timeout\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            continue;
        }

        if (!FD_ISSET(cam_fd, &fds))
            continue;
        
        memset(&buffinfo, 0, sizeof(buffinfo));
        buffinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
        buffinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buffinfo) == -1) {
            if(errno == EAGAIN)
                continue;
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to dequeue buffer\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return -1;
        }

        cam_buffer_index = buffinfo.index;

        memcpy(fb_p, cam_buffers[cam_buffer_index], vinfo.xres*vinfo.yres*4);

        memset(&buffinfo, 0, sizeof(buffinfo));
                buffinfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buffinfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
        buffinfo.index = cam_buffer_index;
                if(ioctl(cam_fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buffinfo) == -1) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: Unable to enqueue buffer\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                        return -1;
                }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output on my screen, You can see on next image:

[image]

I just cannot understand why the output is like that. I typed `fbset -i` command to check info about my framebuffer it says: Its 1280x720, has 32 bpp, and in `rgba` section it says `8/16, 8/8, 8/0, 8/24` (which should mean its in BGRA format). Does anyone encountered this 'weird' behavior before and know what is going on? I have look for logical errors in my code, but was unable to find where did I make mistake.

Also, If somebody have suggestion about this topic I am researching right now, Some advice would really help.

Comment: Your data looks like it is in YUV format rather than RGB. So first you have the complete Y plane, then the half-height/half-width subsampled U and finally the half-height/half-width subsampled V plane. Try Googling YUV420 or see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307044/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the guidance. I will share when I get some results

Comment: Try writing all black pixels to the framebuffer, then all white, then mid-grey and so on until you see a pattern.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried writing all pixels of framebuffer black, gray and white (with `memset(fb_p, 0 [or 128 or 255], vinfo.xres*vinfo.yres*4))` and results are expected. Then I tried to fill with value all red components of pixel and got blue screen, so my framebuffer is indeed in **BGRA** format.

Then my camera buffer is of other format, and I will try to find which. First I will look for **YUYV** since I found one example with same raspberry camera defining that format.  I am not sure that I cam just specify BGRA for camera just like that, maybe I will need to convert it to BGRA later

Comment: @MarkSetchell I figured out what was the problem. I typed `v4l2-ctl --list-formats` to check which formats my camera is supporting and there is no **BGRA**, so it possibly choose one of the possible options: **YU12**, **YUYV**, **RGB3**, **JPEG**, **H264**, **MJPG**, **YVYU**, **VYUY**, **UYVY**, **NV12**, **BGR3**, **YV12**, **NV21** and **RX24**. I chose **BGR3**, copy it to framebuffer with 2 for loops adding alpha value after every BGR component and got right colored image!

Comment: Well done! You can add it as the answer for others in the StackOverflow community to learn from.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for guidance, again! I will give extended answer in answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. I typed `v4l2-ctl --list-formats` to check which formats my camera is supporting and there is no BGRA, so it possibly choose one of the possible options: **YU12**, **YUYV**, **RGB3**, **JPEG**, **H264**, **MJPG**, **YVYU**, **VYUY**, **UYVY**, **NV12**, **BGR3**, **YV12**, **NV21** and **RX24**. I chose **BGR3**, copy it to framebuffer with 2 for loops adding alpha value after every BGR component and got right colored image!

Here Is block of code to populate framebuffer:

```
int offset_data = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vinfo.yres; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vinfo.xres*4; j+=4)
    {
        int idx = i*vinfo.xres*4 + j;
        fb_p[idx] = cam_buffers[cam_buffer_index][offset_data+0];
        fb_p[idx+1] = cam_buffers[cam_buffer_index][offset_data+1];
        fb_p[idx+2] = cam_buffers[cam_buffer_index][offset_data+2];
        fb_p[idx+3] = 0;
        offset_data += 3;
    }
}
```

And, here is the result:

[image]